# Как выровнять текст html

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Имею:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переписывать название с описанием в html блоке, но там не оказалось нужного шрифта. Так выглядит структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнение:

```
<div class="site-branding__body"><h1 class="site-title">О рентгене</h1><p class="site-description">Сайт о рентгене и аппаратной диагностике</p></div></div>
```

Дополнение 2:

```
   echo '<div class="site-branding__body">';

    if ( ! $wpshop_core->get_option( 'header_hide_title' ) ) {
        echo '<' . $site_title_tag . ' class="site-title">' . $site_title_text . '</' . $site_title_tag . '>';
    }
    if ( ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) && ! $wpshop_core->get_option( 'header_hide_description' ) ) {
        echo '<p class="site-description">' . $description . '</p>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас фразы "О рентгене" и "Сайт о рентгене и аппаратной диагностике" должны находиться в одном div и уже этому div надо задать выравнивание text-align:left; (*Это если я понял что именно вам надо выравнивать) Ответ был бы намного проще, если бы вы привели часть html + css данной страницы. По рисункам судить сложно как у вас там все  реализовано

Comment: Прикрепил к посту выше

Comment: @Sevastopol' это шаблон на вордпрессе, я даже толком не соображу как css и html отредактировать там, так чтобы эта надпись потом везде правильно отображалась

Comment: @Sevastopol' вроде нашел фрагмент кода отвечающий за это, прикрепил выше. Не подскажите, что там нужно дописать и где для того, чтобы все выровнять